# What do you call the act of changing camera?

Tags: word-request

In films, you sometimes have the camera focusing on someone's face and then switching to a camera filming something else from a different angle. What do you call the act of switching camera in a film?

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the movie/TV industry may use a different or specific term, but I would call that a [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(transition)).

Comment: For a verb, "to cut to" the new scene would fit.